# How to make layout's content resizable?

Tags: java, layout, javafx, scenebuilder

I've create this in **scene builder** :

[image: Terminal]

[image: Terminal Hierarchy]

My goal is to make this a little more beautiful :

- *Problem 1* : Put the close button in **MAX RIGHT**
- *Problem 2* : **Stick** the differents layouts and TextArea to the window border, because when I resize my window, component does not move.

To do so I want to manipulate the layout properties, but I don't really know how.
I was thinking of **using spacing** for my problem one, but it seems complicated, and I have no idea for resolving my second problem.

Is the choice of my layout correct ? What properties do I have to use for resolving my problems ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase the Problem 2?

Comment: @UlukBiy Done, I can add a picture if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO using `StackPane` for top layout is more appropriate:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    Button b = new Button( "Close" );
    Label l = new Label( "Console" );

    StackPane sp = new StackPane( l, b );
    StackPane.setAlignment( l, Pos.CENTER_LEFT );
    StackPane.setAlignment( b, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT );

    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    VBox.setVgrow( area, Priority.ALWAYS );
    VBox box = new VBox( sp, area );

    Scene scene = new Scene( box, 800, 600 );

    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

But using of `HBox` is unavoidable, add another element to it as a spacer:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    Button b = new Button( "Close" );
    Label l = new Label( "Console" );
    Pane spacer = new Pane();

    HBox hBox = new HBox(l, spacer, b);
    HBox.setHgrow( spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);

    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    VBox.setVgrow( area, Priority.ALWAYS );
    VBox box = new VBox( hBox, area );

    Scene scene = new Scene( box, 800, 600 );

    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to to what you do with the StackPane but with ad HBox ?

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer, what is the :"Vgrow, Hgrow" and the differents priorites ? Very good answer, thank you.

Comment: Basically, these settings control how the additional empty spaces should be shared between the children that the parent layout have, as a result of stage resize for example. For more complete explanation read related javadoc. Also please review oracle's layout tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm